# Put Starcraft 2 trial installation on a USB drive (mac)

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

I want to download the Starcraft 2 trial as a .dmg or a .app file so I can load it onto a usb and plug it into a computer that has slow internet access.  Is that possible?

Comment: Is this question meant to be mac-specific?  I ask because you mentioned `.dmg` and `.app`, but not `.exe`

Comment: It's meant to be mac-specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to copy over the entire `Applications\StarCraft II\` folder from one Mac and move it to another Mac and play it there, without needing to reinstall the game.

If you are playing offline, your saves are in:

```
"Users/[computer user name]/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/Starcraft II/Accounts/[account name]/[number]/saves"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

The Starcraft 2 "Downloader" Application will download an installer for you (which is roughly 7GB in filesize). You can copy this installer package to an UBS-stick and install it on as many machines as you want.